# Wait for a method task to be done before doing anything else

Tags: javascript

I have a class, with methods... one of these actually contains a fetch to get an svg file. Nothing really fancy there.
The problem actually doesn't lie in the class, but when using it.

I have a method getDataFromFile(url), I pass it my SVG url and it does a bunch of stuff. The problem is... When I use it, if I call another method right after it, or even just a console.log... As it hasn't yet fecthed the file, I get "undefined" where it should show an object.

Of course if I set a timeout, it works, but that means that everything after it has to be in a timeout... I could also very well set a timeout in the method called after it, but then this one would become asynchronous too.

I've tried bunch of things, and I don't really get promises and stuff alike so... I'm totally stuck there!

Here's a (very) simplified version of my code, I know it's far from optimal (I'm a begginer) but here it is anyway:

```
var ParentClass = function ()
{
    // Attributes and stuff

    this.paths = [];
}


var MyClass = function ()
{
    ParentClass.call( this );
}


MyClass.prototype.getInlineDOMdata = function ( selector )
{
    // Stuff going on...

    let querySelector = document.querySelectorAll( selector + " path" );

    for ( let i = 0; i < querySelector.length; i++ )
    {
        this.paths.push(
            {
                name: querySelector[ i ].id,
                color: querySelector[ i ].style.fill,
                pathData: querySelector[ i ].attributes.d.value
            }
        );
    }

}


MyClass.prototype.getInlineData = function ( inlineCode )
{
    let domTarget = document.querySelector( "body" );

    domTarget.innerHTML += `<div class="placeholder">${ inlineCode }<div>`;

    let domContainer = document.querySelector( ".placeholder" );

    // Stuff going on...

    this.getInlineDOMdata( ".placeholder svg" );

    domContainer.remove();
}


MyClass.prototype.getDataFromFile = function ( url )
{
    fetch( url )
        .then( response => response.text() )
        .then( data => this.getInlineData( data ));
}
```

Program side it looks like that :

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", loadComplete );

function loadComplete ()
{
    var test = new MyClass();
    test.getInlineData( `
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 195 82">
             <!--Some SVG code -->
     </svg>
      ` );
     console.log( test.paths[ 0 ] ); // Object { name... }
     console.log( test.paths.length ); // 4


    test.getInlineDOMdata( "svg" );
    console.log( test.paths[ 0 ] ); // Object { name... }
    console.log( test.paths.length ); // 4  */

    test.getDataFromFile( "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/ce/SVG-logo.svg" );
    console.log( test.paths[ 0 ] ); // undefined
    console.log( test.paths.length ); // 0

    setTimeout( function ()
    {
        console.log( test.paths[ 0 ] ); // Object { name... }  
        console.log( test.paths.length ); // 4
    }, 1000 );
}
```

So when I use getInlineData, it works.
When I use getInlineDOMdata, it works.
When I use getDataFromFile, it doesn't! But if I put a timer, it does.

I find that really "dirty" and I'm desperate to find a proper solution where I could simply call any other method directly bellow this one!

**EDIT : SOLVED!**

With the use of `async`/`await`, just changing my method `getDataFromFile` to

```
MyClass.prototype.getDataFromFile = async function ( url )
{
    let response = await fetch( url )
        .then( response => response.text() );

    await this.getInlineData( response );
}
```

and program side, adding `async` in front of my `loadComplete` function, and `await` in front of my `test.getDataFromFile( "urlToSvg.svg" );` line solved my issue!

Thanks to Leftium for the great tutarial he provided ([tutorial](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html)), which made me finally get how promises work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). These keywords are basically syntactic sugar for promises, so understanding how promises work will be very helpful.

This is a great [tutorial](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html) that walks through an async example using promises, then converts it to async/await syntax. Relevant quotes:

> The good news is that JavaScript allows you to write
>   pseudo-synchronous code to describe asynchronous computation. An async
>   function is a function that implicitly returns a promise and that can,
>   in its body, await other promises in a way that looks synchronous.

...

> Inside an async function, the word await can be put in front of an
>   expression to wait for a promise to resolve and only then continue the
>   execution of the function.
>
> Such a function no longer, like a regular JavaScript function, runs
>   from start to completion in one go. Instead, it can be frozen at any
>   point that has an await, and can be resumed at a later time.

Comment: I don't know why promises and async concepts are always explained with so much things that it makes them more complicated than they actually are... Fortunately this tutorial was easy to understand and helped me so much, thanks! I finally get it to work exactly as I wanted!

just changing a few words in my getDataFromFile method totally solved my issue, thanks again!